# Create autoincrement primary key for the results of a SELECT clause in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which is created from the result of a SELECT clause. Is there a way to add autoincrement primary key to each row (eg 1, 2, 3,...) My query looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE tableA As( SELECT...some queries);
```

I tried to use:

```
ALTER TABLE tableA  ADD PRIMARY KEY (int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT);
```

..but it didn´t work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL you can execute this query:

```
ALTER TABLE tableA ADD COLUMN id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
```

Comment: One more thing, how do I arrange id column to most left position of the table?

Comment: `ALTER TABLE tableA MODIFY COLUMN id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST;`

Comment: You are legend Jan S! Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

Steps that you can follow are

```
Create Table with Auto Increment Primary Key and all other columns

CREATE TABLE table (
     id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     col1 CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
     col2 CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=XYZ;

Now use Insert Query

Inset Into Table (col1, col2)
(Select col1,col2
//rest of the query)
```

Comment: Thanks but is this the whole query?

Comment: @Best The whole query depends upon your column names e.t.c. But yes, this is complete solution. Simply first create table and then insert rows instead of doing at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @mytable table (id int identity(1,1), other_cols_needed)

insert into @mytable (other_cols)
select * from otherTable
```

should work? (MSSQL syntax)